# AND-OR condition in one if condition

Tags: bash, shell

I have 3 files

```sh
File1=abc.txt File2=def.txt File3=xyz.txt

if [ -f $File1 ] && [ -f $File2 ] && [ -f $File3 ]
then 
   #run some command
```

Else if any of the 3 files don't exist it should tell us which file it is. If it's 2 files that don't exist then it should tell the name for both the files.

Anyone has got any idea how to do that?

Comment: Why do you want all that from _one_ `if` condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first *"if"* of the following script tests if there is one (or more) file missing.
Then if a file is missing, the *"for"* loop on files checks every file individually and displays its name if the file is missing:

```
File1=abc.txt File2=def.txt File3=xyz.txt

if [ ! -f "$File1" -o ! -f "$File2" -o ! -f "$File3" ] ; then
    # At least one file is missing, writing the list of missing file(s):
    echo -n "Missing file(s): "
    for i in "$File1" "$File2" "$File3" ; do 
        if [ ! -f "$i" ] ; then
            echo -n "$i "
        fi
    done        
    echo 
else
    echo "No file is missing"
fi
```

Taking into account Chepner's remark below, a more portable version seems to be:

```
File1=abc.txt File2=def.txt File3=xyz.txt
if [ ! -f "$File1" ] || [ ! -f "$File2" ] || [ ! -f "$File3" ] ; then
    # At least one file is missing, writing the list of missing file(s):
    echo -n "Missing file(s): "
    for i in "$File1" "$File2" "$File3" ; do 
        if [ ! -f "$i" ] ; then
            echo -n "$i "
        fi
    done        
    echo 
else
    echo "No file is missing"
fi
```

Comment: Don't use `-o`; it is non-standard, ambiguous, and obsolete. `[ ... ] || [ ... ] || [ ... ]` is preferred.

Comment: I thought || and && was used to start a sequence of subprocesses.
i.e.: I thought that *x && y* was executing *y* only if *x* returned true. And that *x || y* was executing *y* only if *x* returned false.

Comment: The first part about subprocesses is false (you are probably mixing `&&` with `&`); but yes, `a || b` means run `b` only if `a` failed. Thus `if [ -f first ] || [ -f second ]` succeeds immediately if `first` exists, and otherwise checks if `second` exists, and returns the status of that.

Comment: @Jean-LoupSabatier They are; but you are running separate `[` commands for each comparison, instead of combing the boolean values of each expression in a single command.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily collect the ones which are missing into an array, then take it from there.

```sh
missing=()
for file in abc.txt def.txt xyz.txt; do
    test -e "$file" && continue
    missing+=("$file")
done

if (("${#missing[@]}" == 0 )); then
    # run some command
else
    echo "$0: missing: ${missing[@]}" >&2
fi
```

If you want this to be a one-liner, refactor it into a function; for a simple demo, see https://ideone.com/Oq7cUy